How to take full Screenshot of a scrollable div using Selenium python
As the title suggests, I am trying to take a screenshot of a scrollable div. I attempted to use set_window_size to adjust the browser window to match the dimensions of the scrollable div, but it didn’t work—it didn’t capture the entire element.
Here is my set_window_size function:
def set_window_size(self, el) -> None:
        required_width = (
            self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollWidth", el) + 100
        )
        required_height = (
            self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", el) + 100
        )
        self.driver.set_window_size(required_width, required_height)

I also tried using div.screenshot(path), but that didn’t work either.
Here’s an image of the element I am trying to capture:

